# Full text search in Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The upcoming MongoDB 2.4 supports [full-text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes).

We do this in the mongo shell with a command, such as

```
db.players.runCommand("text", {
    "search": "alice", 
    "project": {"name": 1, "_id": 0}, 
    "limit": 10})
```

Now when porting this to pymongo, we have to deal with the fact that `runCommand` isn't defined on the pymongo `Collection` class.  I was able to figure out what the *real* command was, so this worked in the shell:

```
db.runCommand({
    "text": "players", 
    "search": "alice", 
    "project": {"name": 1, "_id": 0}, 
    "limit": 10})
```

which worked.  But this doesn't exactly tell me how to get this to work in pymongo. I tried:

```
db.command({
    "text":"players", 
    "pipeline": [
        ("search","alice"), ("project",{"name":1,"_id":0}), ("limit",10)
    ]})
```

which did not work (it said "no search specified").  I also tried:

```
db.command({
    "text": "players", 
    "search": "alice", 
    "project": {"name": 1, "_id": 0}, 
    "limit":10})
```

which of course fails with: "no such cmd: project".

I can get things to work if I only use `search` and `limit`, for example

```
db.command({
    "text": "players", 
    "search": "alice",
    "limit": 10})
```

but I would like to use `filter` and `project` with pymongo. Has anyone gotten full-text search working with project and filter?

Aside: Maybe there's a nice way to infer the shape of a pymongo command from a shell command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out: pymongo uses keyword arguments for the additional command arguments:

```
db.command("text", "players", 
    search="alice", 
    project={"name": 1, "_id": 0}, 
    limit=10)
```

The reason for the odd error message "no such cmd: project" is that Python's dictionaries are unordered, and the `project` key happened to be first when passed to mongo.

Comment: Does this work for regex as well? like db.command("regex","players", search="alice")

Comment: I am not familiar with the `regex` command.  It does not appear on [the official list of commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) from MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use OrderedDict. Assuming collection and query are given as variables while additional parameters such as limit, projection and others given in the dict 'params':

```
params_ord = OrderedDict()
params_ord['text'] = collection
params_ord['search'] = query
for k,v in params.iteritems():
    params_ord[k] = v
db.command(params_ord)
```