# Pymongo how to use full text search

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am looking to implement full text search in my python application using pymongo. I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257146/full-text-search-in-pymongo) but for some reason I am unable to implement this in my project as I am getting an error `no such cmd: text`. Can anyone direct me on what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
db = client.test
collection = db.videos
def search_for_videos(self, search_text)
    self.db.command("text", "videos", 
            search=search_text, 
            limit=10)
```

The collection I am trying to search is called `videos` however I am not sure if I am putting this in the correct parameter, and I also am not sure if I need the line `project={"name": 1, "_id": 0}`.

The documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text) I believe is using the mongo shell to execute commands, however I wish to perform this action in my code.

I have looked at using the `db.videos.find()` function, but cannot seem to implement it correctly either.

**How to I use PyMongo Full Text Search from my Python Code?**

Comment: Please also note that you will have to write `"_id": False` in Pymongo instead of the `"_id": 0` for plain MongoDB.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First be sure that you have a text index created on the field as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) or you can just do it with pymongo too :

```
collection.create_index([('your field', 'text')])
```

Using pymongo you can do this to search:

```
collection.find({"$text": {"$search": your search}})
```

your function should look like this:

```
def search_for_videos(search_text):
    collection.find({"$text": {"$search": search_text}}).limit(10)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: According to current documentation, `create_index(...)` accepts list of tuples, where 2-nd parameter is order (asc|desc). Though using `'text'` as a 2-nd parameter worked for me

Answer (score 1):

First create a text index based on the field you want to do the search on.

> from pymongo import TEXT
>
> db = MongoClient('localhost',port = 27017).DBNAME
>
> db.collection.create_index([('FIELD_NAME',TEXT)],default_language ="english")

once you create the text index use the following query to search text. Depending on the size of your database, it might take long to create the text index.

> db.collection.find({"$text": {"$search": your search}})